# How to remove duplicate characters?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

If I am having a line as:

```
Thhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee
```

I want to print this as:

```
This is my name
```

What is the unix command for this?

Comment: Can you provide some more context on the origin of the duplications and desired output? What if "Mmyyy nameee iisss Jesssssiiieee"?

Answer (score 39):

With `tr`:

```
echo "Thhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee" | tr -s 'a-z'
```

Explanation: The `-s` switch of `tr` "squeezes" repeat characters. As shown, the switch can be used with a range of characters: `a` to `z`.

Answer (score 9):

One way with `sed`:

```
sed ':X;s/\(.\)\1/\1/g;tX'
```

or even simpler:

```
sed 's/\(.\)\1*/\1/g'
```

(thanks *Costas* and *mikeserv* for comments).

Comment: `sed 's/\(.\)\1\+/\1/g'`

Answer (score 8):

On a GNU system you'll need to use `sed` or similar if your locale uses multibyte characters *([as jimmij suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187053/52934))* because GNU `tr` can only reference a character per byte. In an ASCII locale you can remove *all* duplicates w/ `tr` like:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -s '\0-\255' <input
```

So...

```
echo Thhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee|
LC_ALL=C tr -s '\0-\255'
```

...prints...

```
This is my name
```

You can also do it selectively by referring to your targets by range:

```
echo TThhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee|
LC_ALL=C tr -s '\101-\132'
```

...or...

```
echo TTTThhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee|
LC_ALL=C tr -s '[:upper:]'
```

...which work out to be the same thing, and which both print:

```
Thhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee
```

...or use `[:punct:]`, `[:digit:]`, `[:lower:]`, `[:alpha:]` or whatever you would like. You can also negate the selection w/ `-c` so...

```
echo 'TTTThhiisss     iisss mmyyy nameeee' |
LC_ALL=C tr -cs '[:upper:]'
```

...prints...

```
TTTThis is my name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `tr`:

```
echo "Thhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee" | tr -s 'hismye'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "Thhiisss iisss mmyyy nameeee" | grep -o . | uniq | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).